# What are some reasons that `reactor.callFromThread(func)` will not work

Tags: python, twisted, reactor

I am trying to debug an issue such that `reactor.callFromThread(func)` won't do anything

Currently, I have a function that perform an exiting operation, including closing files...etc

```
def exit(self):
    try:
        def clean_handler():
            exit_handler()

        self.reactor.callFromThread(clean_handler) # doesn't work
        # clean_handler() # this works
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

I tried print out the reactor to check if it exists, and try writing some dummy function to test on `callFromThread` and I am getting the conclusion that although the reactor exist, the `callFromThread` simply doesn't do anything.

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please attach an actual example of the problem.  I could randomly guess, but I've never seen this particular function fail, so the guesses wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, can you specify what you want to see, the code base is actually pretty large, but I believe I have isolate the cause, as `clean_handler` don't get call at all

Comment: Create a minimal example of the problem that includes only the absolute minimum from your codebase to reproduce it.  See http://sscce.org/